# Autoincrement numeric element of a string on copy down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, concatenation

My first row in Excel is `"http://somepath/001.jpg"` and I have 2000 images. I want that:

my 1st row is `"http://somepath/001.jpg"`
my 2nd row is `"http://somepath/002.jpg"`
..
..
my 2000th row is `"http://somepath/2000.jpg"`

How can I add these in Excel in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Excel macros code.

```
Sub Macro()
    For i = 1 To 2000
        'in place of 1 specify which column you want to insert the image
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:= _
            "path\image" & i & ".jpg", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
            True, IconFileName:= _
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", _
            IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:="path\image" & i & ".jpg").Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

Below are the steps I followed:

1. I write my path in 1st row till number i.e. `"http://somepath/001"`
2. I click on right corner of cell and drag it till 2000 row
3. Now I have 2000 rows with last row is `"http://somepath/2000"` and so I select another column i.e. B and use Excel CONCATENATE function. ex. `=CONCATENATE(A1, ".jpg")`
4. Again click on right corner of cell(i.e. B1) and drag it till 2000 row.
5. Now we have rows with `"http://somepath/001.jpg"` to `"http://somepath/2000.jpg"` so Select column i.e. B right click copy
6. Select another column right click and select Values Option from Paste

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:

```
="http://somepath/"&TEXT(ROW(),"0000")&".jpg"
```